# Complex processing of SELECT-query results in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

There's a stored procedure with many UPDATEs in it (for many tables).
I need to do something like logging for this updates, but with **no triggers**.

It's easy to make SP which takes one row + table name and adds record to log-table. And it's also easy to form SELECTs with updated records.

I wish to find the way to do something like

```
MAKE_LOG
FROM (
  SELECT "tblName", EventID, ID
  FROM ...
)
```

"MAKE_LOG" - is just an example-name. I'm searching for way to handle tables with stored procedures. Maybe, something like table valued parameters. And it would be better to find something compatible with **SQL Server 2005**.

I could use cursors, but syntax looks not really laconic (probably I should put it into function).

Maybe, there's another way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spLog
AS
SELECT * FROM #log
GO


DECLARE @t1 TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), Name NVARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @t2 TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), Name NVARCHAR(MAX))
create TABLE #log (ID INT, TableName NVARCHAR(MAX), Act NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @t1 
OUTPUT Inserted.ID, '@t1', 'INSERT' INTO #log
VALUES('Table1 Value1')

INSERT INTO @t2 
OUTPUT Inserted.ID, '@t2', 'INSERT' INTO #log
VALUES('Table2 Value1')

INSERT INTO @t1 
OUTPUT Inserted.ID, '@t1', 'INSERT' INTO #log
VALUES('Table1 Value2')

UPDATE @t2
SET Name = 'New Name'
OUTPUT Inserted.ID, '@t2', 'UPDATE' INTO #log

DELETE 
FROM @t1
OUTPUT deleted.ID, '@t1', 'DELETE' INTO #log

EXEC dbo.spLog

DROP TABLE #log
```

Output:

```
ID  TableName   Act
1   @t1         INSERT
1   @t2         INSERT
2   @t1         INSERT
1   @t2         UPDATE
1   @t1         DELETE
2   @t1         DELETE
```

From 2008 you can create user defined table type, fill it and pass to stored proc:

```
CREATE TYPE LogTableType AS TABLE
(
    ID INT, 
    TableName NVARCHAR(MAX), Act NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spLog
@Log LogTableType READONLY
AS
SELECT * FROM @Log
GO


DECLARE @t1 TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), Name NVARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @t2 TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), Name NVARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @log LogTableType

INSERT INTO @t1 
OUTPUT Inserted.ID, '@t1', 'INSERT' INTO @log
VALUES('Table1 Value1')

INSERT INTO @t2 
OUTPUT Inserted.ID, '@t2', 'INSERT' INTO @log
VALUES('Table2 Value1')

INSERT INTO @t1 
OUTPUT Inserted.ID, '@t1', 'INSERT' INTO @log
VALUES('Table1 Value2')

UPDATE @t2
SET Name = 'New Name'
OUTPUT Inserted.ID, '@t2', 'UPDATE' INTO @log


DELETE 
FROM @t1
OUTPUT deleted.ID, '@t2', 'DELETE' INTO @log

EXEC dbo.spLog @log
```

Comment: Looks, like good solution! I guess there's no way to do something similar in **SQL Server 2005** (I mean table valued SP) ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what your proposal is, but it looks like you want to wrap a bunch of SQL statements and somehow magically log the changes... which would indeed be magic.

Instead, do as you suggest in the question and create a stored proc that you can simply pass a few parameters to, which will insert a log entry for you. Then just call it after each update.

**Sample:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertLogEntry]
    @UserId INT = NULL ,
    @Table NVARCHAR(256) ,
    @EventId INT ,
    @Id INT
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON 

        INSERT  INTO LogTable
                ( UserId, [Table], EventId, Id )
        VALUES  ( @UserId, @Table, @EventId, @Id )  
    END
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way of how to do it with one row updated. But how to apply it, if UPDATE is based on SELECT of big subset (usually it is so)?